# How to display wordpress ACF plugin custom image field image

Tags: wordpress, image, post, advanced-custom-fields, meta-boxes

I have used ACF plugin to add custom post meta box image field. My custom image field name is **homepage_full_width**.

How can i display post thumbnail image using this custom field image.

thanks.

Comment: This one is my ACF field admin side settings -> http://nimb.ws/lKmhFe

Answer (score 3):

You can use image ID as the return type of the ACF custom image field then you can use the `wp_get_attachment_image()` function to generate the image HTML.

```
$image = get_field('homepage_full_width');
$size = 'thumbnail'; // (thumbnail, medium, large, full or custom size)

if( $image ) {

    echo wp_get_attachment_image( $image, $size );

}
```

**UPDATE**

Use **image Object** as the return type then try

```
<?php 
$imageBg = get_field('homepage_full_width'); 
$bg = $imageBg ? $imageBg['url'] : ''; 
?>
<div class="zl-homefullwidth-img parallax_bg skrollable skrollable-between" style="transform: translate3d(0px, 0.382158%, 0px);background-image: url(<?php echo $bg; ?>)"></div>
```

Comment: I have added above code like this and also changed image Object to image ID. But in background url display blank:

`<div class="zl-homefullwidth-img parallax_bg skrollable skrollable-between" style="transform: translate3d(0px, 0.382158%, 0px);background-image: url(<?php $image = get_field('homepage_full_width');
$size = 'full'; if( $image ) {  echo wp_get_attachment_image( $image, $size ); }  ?>)"></div>
`

Comment: Sorry, Last code also not working. In image url display blank.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it two ways:

1. you can use the `get_field('homepage_full_width')` in your themes php files where you want it, you can see the documention for it [here](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/)
2. You can use and shortcode to display it: `[acf field="homepage_full_width"]`

You can read the documention for the shortcode [here](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/shortcode/)

Comment: Which one of the code did you try? and I saw that the shortcode only works with text, so you will need to use the first on

Comment: Please review my above attached screen shot and i want to display that custom post meta_box image in place of this -> http://nimb.ws/mFXJ1e post featured image. 

Thanks.

Comment: Using bellow code i have displayed post original featured image before:
`<div id="lead-article" class="post featured-style10 post-header">
<div  data-interchange="[<?php echo $lead_article_img_horizontal_src ?>, landscape], [<?php echo $lead_article_img_vertical_src ?>, portrait]" class="zl-homefullwidth-img parallax_bg skrollable skrollable-between" data-bottom-top="transform: translate3d(0px, -20%, 0px);" data-top-bottom="transform: translate3d(0px, 20%, 0px);" style="transform: translate3d(0px, 0.382158%, 0px);background-image: url(<?php echo $lead_article_img_horizontal_src ?>)"></div>`

Comment: Okej, before that code, you can use `<?php $image = get_field('homepage_full_width'); ?>` to get the image, and where you have your source you can use `<?php echo $image['sizes']['large']; ?>` where the last is the size you want. or you can get the original file with `<?php echo $image['url']; ?>`

Comment: Do you get any errors, or did the did it not do anythings, also can you add the code you tried to run?